# How to open an image and put something in it

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an image that has some blank space I need to put some numbers inside blank spaces and save a new image there is no need to show anything as UI and all things will do in the background
my question is :
1-how open an image in the background
2-how put another image in a specific place in it
3-how save a new image

Comment: Your Question is not clear enough, mate.

Comment: Okay. You should delete the question,I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer
1- I put the image in assets :

```
    private fun String?.getBitmapFromAssets() : Bitmap? {
    val assetManager : AssetManager = context.assets
    val inst : InputStream = assetManager.open(this !!)
    val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inst)
    val mutableBitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 , true)
    inst.close()
    return mutableBitmap
}
```

2- to create text :

```
    val canvas = Canvas(bitmap !!)
    val paint = Paint()
    paint.color = Color.BLACK
    paint.textSize = 23F
    paint.typeface = Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD
    canvas.drawText("text", 635f , 371f ,paint)
    view.draw(canvas)
```

3- to save a new image :

```
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,90,file)
```

finally, close it :

```
    file.flush()
    file.close()
```